# Finding what it redirects to

Tags: php

I'm using the "Snoopy" class to pick up HTML for phrasing.

The problem is that with one of the pages I need to get the html for redirects automatically because I'm using a the sites search and if it find a perfect result it will redirect.

Here is my snoop:

```
if($snoopy->fetch("http://www.rottentomatoes.com/search/?search=$pagelink&sitesearch=rt")){ 
$printable = $snoopy->results;
```

If the search is exact it will place me on a page like this...

> http://www.rottentomatoes.com/m/captain-america/

I need this above link.

Any help would be great,

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From poking around in the code a little, it seems like you should be able to check the variable `$snoopy->lastredirectaddr`, which should be set if you got redirected (if not, it should be a blank string).

Comment: How did you try using it? I tried it out on my own, and after a `fetch` that resulted in a redirect, `$snoopy->lastredirectaddr` contained the redirect URL.